# HTML video player for multiple files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, video

So here is the problem I am faced with. I have Season 3 of The Walking Dead that consists of 16 .mp4 videos. I have made a very simple way of playing them in browser with a HTML master page and a play button for each episode. Then, on click it will open another HTML page with the video frame for that episode. So in my Season 3 folder, I have an Index.html page and then 16 more pages that are for the relevant videos. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this?

What I would really like is to have is a link for 'Season 3 Episode 1' and on click it will open that video but without having to have 16 extra html pages just to play one video. Is there a way to do this with an 'Index' page and then a 'Player' page that will play the video requested? Is this something that could be done with PHP? So on click for 'Season 3 Episode 1', it will pull a video called S03E01.mp4 in the player page. Then for 'Season 3 Episode 2' it will open the same Player page but open S03E02.mp4?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried changing `src` of `video` element ?

Comment: AJAX? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516202/loading-flash-videos-into-div-with-ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do in only one page is this html :

```
<video controls autoplay>
    <source src="S01E01.mp4">
    <source src="S01E02.mp4">
    <source src="S01E03.mp4">
    <source src="S01E04.mp4">
</video>
```

This allows you to have a sort of playlist

Else in your index page you could have things like this :

```
<a href="player.php?ep=E01&s=S02" target="_blank">Season 2 Episode 1</a>
<a href="player.php?ep=E02&s=S01" target="_blank">Season 1 Episode 2</a>
<a href="player.php?ep=E03&s=S03" target="_blank">Season 3 Episode 3</a>
<a href="player.php?ep=E04&s=S01" target="_blank">Season 1 Episode 4</a>
```

`target="_blank"` will open the player in a new tab/window.
And in your player.php file :

```
<video src="<?php echo($_GET['s']); echo($_GET['ep']); ?>.mp4" controls autoplay></video>
```

The video source will be the text after `?s=` + the text after `?ep=` + `.mp4`

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the reply. It might help if I show you my file structure. I have as follows: index.html, player.php and then all of the videos. So S03E01.mp4, S03E02.mp4, S03E03.mp4 and so on, all the way to 16. I have tried the method you have suggested and it doesn't load the video. It just shows the video player box and nothing more. Thanks again.

Comment: Which one did you try ? If it's the second one, it's supposed to work for your file structure. Can you send me one of your `<a ...>` line of your index.html and the `<video ...>` line of your player.php file ?

Comment: Hey. Fixed it! It was my own fault. I forgot to change a name for the season, meaning it wasn't finding the file! Thanks for the help! It works flawlessly!

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have on your html

```
<div id="elvideo"></div>
```

Then you could do this

```
<script>
var str = "S03E01.mp4,S03E02.mp4,S03E03.mp4,....,S03E0(n).mp4";
var n = str.includes(","); 
if (n) {
var nArr = str.split(',');
    document.getElementById('elvideo').innerHTML ="<video id='videoElement' width=100% controls controlsList='nodownload' autoplay playsinline><p>Tu navegador no funciona, actualizalo</p></video>";
var videoPlayer = document.getElementById('videoElement');
videoPlayer.src = "http://pathtoyour/file/video/"+nArr[0];
i = 1;
videoPlayer.onended = function(){
    if (i < nArr.length) {
        videoPlayer.src = "http://pathtoyour/file/video/"+nArr[i]
       i++
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This will start with first mp4 and when it finish playing, will go to next one and so on. 
You could place on screen control image (as Netflix does) to go back and forward using your array of mp4 at **nArr[x]**

If you want to skip several programs without going thru all the programs in between, then you need to add a dropdown list of the episodes somewhere. and do an "onclick" jump function to play that specific episode mp4.